# How to call PowerShell function written in ps1 script?

Tags: powershell

New to powershell, I want to write a PS function like this:

```
function InvokeTest {
    param (
        [string]$OutputPath,
        [string]$Version
    )
    $OutputPath
}
```

in terminal, I copied the function content to the prompt, then I can invoke the InvokeTest() direct with parameter -OutputPath. The result is ok.

```
PS D:\> function InvokeTest {
>>     param (
>>         [string]$OutputPath,
>>         [string]$Version
>>     )
>>     $OutputPath
>> }
PS D:\> 
PS D:\> InvokeTest -OutputPath "hello,world"
hello,world
```

I have a file named invokeTest.ps1 which contains only the function InvokeTest.

I know I can use ".\invokeTest.ps1" in terminal prompt to run the script but how can I specify the "outputpath" parameter ?

I tried these ways:

```
.\InvokeTest.ps1 -OutputPath "hello"
.\InvokeTest.ps1 InvokeTest -OutputPath "hello"
```

But they didn't work.

I know a way to solve this issue but it's not elegant,

```
function InvokeTest {
    param (
        [string]$OutputPath,
        [string]$Version
    )
    Write-Host $OutputPath,$Version
}
InvokeTest -OutputPath $args[0] -Version $args[1]
```

then use

```
PS D:\> .\InvokeTest.ps1 "hello,world","123"
hello,world 123 
PS D:\>
```

But if there are many parameters, one or more parameters may be optional, how can I specify parameters I really need to pass .

Comment: Split it into two operations - 1) execute the function definition in the current scope, 2) then invoke the function: `. .\InvokeTest.ps1; InvokeTest -OutputPath "hello,world" -Version 123`

Comment: If you "dot source" your "InvokeTest.ps1" script (e.g. ```. .\InvokeTest.ps1```) it will run the script in the current scope and make the ```InvokeTest``` function available to be called in your main script like ```InvokeTest -OutputPath "hello,world"``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.2#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing

Answer (score 0):

In principle if you write functions you should store them in a module (*.psm1). Once you did this you can store the module in a location covered by the environment variable PsModulePath = no need to import the module. Otherwise you have to import the module:

```
import-module [path]
```

Once the module is loaded you can call all functions which it contains from the shell. You should always use named parameters, as you did, in functions. So the right call of the function would be:

```
invoketest -OutputPath [value] -Version [value]
```

About functions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2

About modules:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7.2

About Parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2

About PsModulePath: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-7.2

Also you should consider the format of functions:

```
[verb]-[noun]
```

To get a list of "approved" verbs:

```
get-verb
```

Comment: yeah, this method works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Function-File` and call it like `tmp1.ps1 -OutputPath 'Eshkere'`

```
#FILE START
param (
    [string]$OutputPath="DefaultPath",
    [string]$Version="DefaultVersion"
)

Function Get-CapitalizedString([string]$Value) {
    return $Value.ToUpperInvariant()
}

    
Write-Host (Get-CapitalizedString -Value $OutputPath),$Version
#FILE END
```